# React native clear user data on app update (android)

Tags: react-native

i want clear user Data storage (Setting > App > Clear Storage) on when user update the app

of course i wont put it on every update but sometime there's an update that need to reset the user data storage so its basically like fresh install

anyway to achieve this ?

Answer (score -3):

you can use  `AsyncStorage.clear()` for clearing storage data on your app.

```
if((updatedVersion === currentVersion) && nowUpdated){
   AsyncStorage.clear()
}
```